# How can I determine which of two independent variables influences the other one?

Tags: correlation, independence

I am a uni student in my final semester and I am in the midst of writing the proposal for my Bachelor's thesis.

For my topic I want to research the correlation between gender diversity and innovation in companies, more specifically if gender diversity causes more innovation **or** if innovative firms get more gender diverse by themselves. So basically I have two independent variables(?) and need to find out which variable influences the other one.

As the question is sorta vague, I haven't found anything specific on the internet and none of my friends could answer this question either. 
I am happy with a helpful link or even just a cue how to scientifically do this.

Comment: You are right, it is vague. Have you thought of correlation or regression? There are loads of posts on the site about both. I do not think you are going to get much handle on causality without longitudinal data.

Answer (score 1):

You have left out a third possibility: The two might not influence each other but could be influenced by a third one, which you have not investigated. If an old CEO leads to little gender diversity and little innovation, then both will be correlated without one of them necessarily influencing the other.

With observational data like the ones described you can really only test for correlation, not for influence. The necessary step to really proove influnce would be experimentation. If you could change one aspect in an experiment and could observe, it the other is changed, too. That would proove influence.